# Android Storing Dynamic Bitmaps in an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, bitmap, android-arrayadapter, break

I am working on creating the n-puzzle in android. I am able to break up my bitmap but i cannot store it an arrayadapter to pass to a listview. Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.